# Let X and Y be jointly distributed random variables having the joint probability density function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be jointly distributed random
variables having the joint probability
density function
[
f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
            \frac{1}{\pi}, &\text{if}\quad x^2 + y^2 \leq 1\\
             0, &\text{otherwise}\\
            \end{cases}

Then $P(Y > |X|)$ is

I tried writing integration for this but I am getting wrong. I tried writing cdf for this function as well but that did not help. How should I proceed further?

Comment: Please show us what you have done.

Comment: $P(|X|<Y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_0^{|x|}f_{xy}(x,y)dxdy$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A figure indicating the range of $(X, Y)$ often helps to determine the integral bounds and solve problems like this.

In this problem, the range of $(X, Y)$ is given by $0 \leq x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$, which is the unit circle (showing below).

[image]

Since the area of the unit circle is $\pi \times 1^2 = \pi$ and given that
$$f(x,y) = \frac{1}{\pi} \quad \text{if } x^2 + y^2 \leq 1,$$
and 0 otherwise, we conclude that $(X, Y)$ is uniformly distributed over the unit circle (think about why this is true).

Next, we want to find $P(Y > \left|X\right|)$. Since $(X, Y)$ is uniformly distributed, the problem reduces to finding the ratio between areas of the region defined by the event $\{Y > \left|X\right|\}$ (i.e. highlighted in light blue) and the unit circle. From the figure we can see that the highlighted region is in fact a quarter of the unit circle (the angle between $y = x$ and $y = -x$ is 90 degrees), we have
$$P(Y > \left|X\right|) = \frac{\frac{1}{4}\pi}{\pi} = \frac{1}{4}.$$

Remark: This approach makes use of the property of uniform distribution, which bypasses calculating the integral. If we do want to solve this problem using the integral approach, note that
\begin{align*}
P(Y > \left|X\right|) &= \iint_{\{y > \left|x\right|\}} f(x,y) dxdy\\
&= \iint_{\{y > \left|x\right|, \ x^2 + y^2 \leq 1\}} \frac{1}{\pi} dxdy\\
&= \frac{1}{\pi} \iint_{\{y > \left|x\right|, \ x^2 + y^2 \leq 1\}} dxdy\\
&= \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4} \int_0^1 rdrd\theta \quad (\text{polar coordinate})\\
&= \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4} \left[\frac{1}{2}r^2\right]\bigg|_0^1 d\theta\\
&= \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4} \frac{1}{2} d\theta\\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi} \left[\frac{3\pi}{4} - \frac{\pi}{4}\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi} \cdot \frac{\pi}{2}\\
&= \frac{1}{4}.
\end{align*}
More details on polar coordinate transformation can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system).

Answer (score 1):

$(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed on the unit disk (the disk centered in the origin with radius 1), thus geometrically you immediately get that

$$\mathbb{P}(Y>|X|)=\frac{1}{4}$$

No calculations are needed, just a geometric observation because the favourable area is $\frac{1}{4}$ of the total disk

Comment: But I need a written method to prove it. I tried a graphical approach which works but cannot get the exact arguments to write